# in Frimware updater the part 'DBX revocation list " disappeared after update

Tags: uefi

When I saw the notification to update the device 'UEFI DBX revocation list' from version 220 to version 310 I did the update but after that I did not get a notice that it was succeeded. so nothing happened afterwards. Than I rebooted and started again the firmware updater . I saw no mention of the DBX revocation UEFI version. Only the other devices are shown (hard discs, SSD, ...) . Is it normal that the device 'DBX revocation UEFI' is disappeared after the update ? If not , how can I fix this to see again the device 'DBX revocation UEFI' in the firmware updater ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the installation is failing but the error log isn't showing. Maybe try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1497749/8583).